# Binary seach tree, remove node, need help here (reposting)

Tags: python, methods, binary-search-tree

My code is looking like this:

```
class Treenode:
    def __init__(self,data,left=None,right=None):
        self.data=data
        self.left=left
        self.right=right

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)

    def delete(self):
        child=self.left
        grandchild=child.right
        print(grandchild)
        if self.left == self.right==None:
            return None
        if self.left==None:
            return self.right
        if self.right==None:
            return self.left
        if grandchild:
            while grandchild.right:
                child = grandchild
                grandchild = child.right
            self.data = grandchild.data
            child.right = grandchild.left
        else:
            self.left = child.left
            self.data = child.data
        return self

class Bintree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def put(self,data):
        if self.root == None:
            self.root = Treenode(data)
            return
        p = self.root
        while True:
            if data < p.data:
                if p.left == None:
                    p.left = Treenode(data)
                    return
                else:
                    p = p.left
            elif data > p.data:
                if p.right == None:
                    p.right = Treenode(data)
                    return
                else:
                    p = p.right
            elif data == p.data:
                return False
            else:
                return

    def exists(self, data):
        return finns(self.root, data)

    def isempty(self):
        return self.root == None

    def height(self):
        def hp(tree):
            if tree is None:
                return 0
            else:
                return 1 + max(hp(tree.left), hp(tree.right))
        return hp(self.root)

    def printTree(self):
        skriv(self.root)

    def remove(self, data):
        if self.root and self.root.data == data:  #self.root kanske inte behövs, undersök
            self.root = self.root.delete()
            return
        else:
            parent = self.root
            while parent:
                if data < parent.data:
                    child = parent.left
                    if child and child.data== data:
                        parent.left = child.delete()
                        return
                    parent = child
                else:
                    child = parent.right
                    if child and child.data == data:
                        parent.right = child.delete()
                        return
                    parent = child



def skriv(tree):
    if tree == None:
        return
    skriv(tree.left)
    print(tree.data)
    skriv(tree.right)

def finns(roten, key):
    if roten == None:
        return False
    if key == roten.data:
        return True
    elif key < roten.data:
        return finns(roten.left, key)
    else:
        return finns(roten.right, key)
```

Everything about my code is working, and I've simply added (see copied) the delete method and the remove method. Im desperately trying to understand the delete-method but I cannot understand it. I use this code to run the thing and see how the tree is implemented:

```
from labb8test import Bintree
from labb8test import Treenode

tree = Bintree()    
tree.put(8)    
tree.put(3)
tree.put(1)
tree.put(6)
tree.put(4)
tree.put(7)
tree.put(10)
tree.put(14)
tree.put(13)
tree.remove(6)
tree.printTree()
```

I'm trying to draw it on a paper and see, especially how the while-loop is working. According to my above code, I would think it is like this:

child = self.left (child=3) grandchild= child.right=self,left.right=6. If grandchild (yes, 6) while grandchild.right (yes, 7) child = grandchild, 3-->6 grandchild = child.right (is this even needed, 6--->6?) self.data=grandchild.data (8--->6) child.right = grandchild.left (6---->4) ??

But it cannot be like this, because then the while-loop would never end. Is there anyone who can help me understanding where I lose myself?

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what you mean when you describe what you think it would look like.  Also, you may like a tool called a "debugger", it lets you watch the code execute.  Here is a free one online: http://www.pythontutor.com

Comment: that tool is worth gold, thank you so much for that one, finally I can track down where everything went wrong!

Comment: Im trying to debugg it right now, I have one issue, when I enter the while grandchild.right then I set grandchild=child.right, but how can child.right be  7 during the first while-loop?

Comment: Ive been trying to write this code down at paper like 50 times, I cannot, still, understand how the BST attributes still are there when I do this stuff...

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you this material from algorithm Princeton:
http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/32bst/

The delete method is using this approach to delete a node from a bst.

> Delete. We can proceed in a similar manner to delete any node that has
>   one child (or no children), but what can we do to delete a node that
>   has two children? We are left with two links, but have a place in the
>   parent node for only one of them. An answer to this dilemma, first
>   proposed by T. Hibbard in 1962, is to delete a node x by replacing it
>   with its successor. Because x has a right child, its successor is the
>   node with the smallest key in its right subtree. The replacement
>   preserves order in the tree because there are no keys between x.key
>   and the successor's key. We accomplish the task of replacing x by its
>   successor
>
> in four (!) easy steps:
>
> - Save a link to the node to be deleted in t
> - Set x to point to its successor min(t.right)
> - Set the right link of x (which is supposed to point to the BST    containing all the keys larger than x.key) to deleteMin(t.right), the 
>     link to the BST containing all the keys that are larger than x.key
>     after the deletion.
> - Set the left link of x (which was null) to t.left (all the keys that    are less than both the deleted key and its successor).

[image]

Comment: Hello Alcruz, "link only" answers are discouraged here, because if the link breaks, the answer is no longer useful.  Please consider moving the relevant part of the linked content to the answer.

Comment: @MackM. Thanks for the information, I'm kind of new in this.

Comment: Im very thankful that someone brings me some information at this point, gonna read that one closely, I would say that I understand the basics, that means, I understand what I want to do, but im unsure how my code does that, if you look at what I wrote last, when does it go wrong for me ?